# Satoshi introduced the 1MB block size limit in a commit. Why did Andresen make an identical commit some days later?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, history, blocksize

Satoshi added the 1MB block size limit in this commit on 15 July 2010

- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/a30b56ebe76ffff9f9cc8a6667186179413c6349
- https://sourceforge.net/p/bitcoin/code/103

Why did Andresen make an identical commit on 19 Jul 2010?

- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/9d2174b6f5f3fac2463c7ebc2dbb9004b3740d23

I realise it was enforced in a later commit via UASF, but the question remains, why are there two identical commits? Have I misunderstood the workflow? Did Andresen make changes when transitioning from SourceForge to GitHub in 2011?

TLDR: What is the purpose of two identical commits with different dates in the GitHub history?

Comment: It's probably an artifact of the migration from Sourceforge to Github. Sourceforge uses the SVN version control system while Github uses Git so moving from one to the other might leave behind some weirdness.

Comment: Would you mind posting that as an answer, @AndrewChow?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably an artifact of the migration from Sourceforge to Github. Sourceforge uses the SVN version control system while Github uses Git so moving from one to the other might leave behind some weirdness.